# Mono for Android - Layout Designer Issue

Tags: android, layout, mono, designer

I'm using Mono for Android 4.2.4 with VS 2010. The layout designer does not refresh properly if you change the theme, API version, orientation or device name from the designer toolbar. MonoDevelop works fine.

Is there a resolution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen one. There are other issues as well, if you modify a xaml file and change widows without saving it, your changes will disappear! While Monodroid is an awesome tool, there are still a few bugs